# objective c - why does alert and actionsheet's button text disappear when iphone settings : "Darken Colors" is turned on

Tags: objective-c, text, alert

Here's my problem:

When I turn on settings
"General" - "Accessibility" - "Increase Contrast" - "Darken Colors"
and open the APP
the button's text of alert and actionsheet disappears(like the pictures above), 
if I turn off "Darken Colors" now, it's still gone.

But if I turn off the "Darken Colors" then open the APP,
it's normal.

This is my code:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"你確定要撥打?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"取消" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"確定" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:xxxx-xxx-xxx"]];
                           }];
[alert addAction:okAction];
[alert addAction:cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: Alert]

[image: ActionSheet]

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this. We present our alerts in their own `UIWindow` and setting the tint color of the window caused this issue.

`alertWindow.tintColor = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.tintColor`

Removing the line above resolved the issue for me. 
Perhaps you are setting your main window tint color somewhere?